# Get nationality of person using DBPedia and SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?nationalityLabel WHERE {
  dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen dbpedia-owl:nationality ?nationality .
  ?nationality rdfs:label ?nationalityLabel .
}
```

I have checked that Henrik Ibsen exists and that he has the nationality ontology/property on him:
http://dbpedia.org/page/Henrik_Ibsen

And this is an ontology:
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/nationality

A very similar query to this listed here works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10248653/1680130

The problem I have is that the query doesn't return any result.

If I could get help solving this it would be great.

**Summarized solution:**
Both answers were great so upvote to both but landed on Joshua's in the end because informing about dbpedia-owl being cleaner. Optimal solution in my opinion:

First check with dbpedia-owl for birth-place:

```
select ?label { 
 dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen
   dbpedia-owl:birthPlace
     [ a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
       rdfs:label ?label ]
 filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
}
```

If found then get the demonym:

```
select ?label { 
 dbpedia:Norway dbpedia-owl:demonym ?label
 filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
}
```

If above fails then do the "dirty" query:

```
SELECT
  ?nationality
WHERE {
  dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen dbpprop:nationality ?nationality .
 filter langMatches(lang(?nationality),"en")
}
```

Of course is "dirty" means data being correct but not so often present the order might be better other way around because people can be born in a country but from a different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kristian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21846244/1281433) is right that the property is `dbpprop:nationality` that Henrik Ibsen has.  You're right that there is a `dbpedia-owl:nationality` property, too, but Henrik Ibsen doesn't have a value for it, unfortunately.  The value of `dbpprop:nationality` that Henrik Ibsen has, though, is a string, which is a literal, and literals cannot be the subjects of triples in RDF, so `?nationality rdfs:label ?nationalityLabel` in your query will never match.

The DBpedia ontology data (`dbpedia-owl`) tends to be cleaner than the `dbpprop` data, so you might prefer a solution using `dbpedia-owl` properties that Henrik Ibsen does have.  In this case, you might look to the `dbpedia-owl:birthPlace`.  Then you could get the name the country of the birth places:

```
select ?label { 
 dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen
   dbpedia-owl:birthPlace
     [ a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
       rdfs:label ?label ]
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?label%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen%0D%0A%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Country%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs:label%20?label%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You might want to narrow the permissible languages:

```
select ?label { 
 dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen
   dbpedia-owl:birthPlace
     [ a dbpedia-owl:Country ;
       rdfs:label ?label ]
 filter langMatches(lang(?label),"en")
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?label%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen%0D%0A%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Country%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs:label%20?label%20%5D%0D%0A%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28?label%29,%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Those queries will produce the name of the country, but it wanted the corresponding [demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym), you can get the `dbpedia-owl:demonym` value of the country, if it's available.  It's probably best to make the demonym optional, since a cursory investigation suggests that lots of countries in DBpedia don't have a value for it, so the name of the country may be the only option.  E.g.,

```
select ?name ?demonym { 
  dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?country .
  ?country a dbpedia-owl:Country ; rdfs:label ?name .
  optional { ?country dbpedia-owl:demonym ?demonym }

  filter langMatches(lang(?name),"en")
  filter langMatches(lang(?demonym),"en")
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?name%20?demonym%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%20?country%20.%0D%0A%20%20?country%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Country%20;%20rdfs:label%20?name%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20?country%20dbpedia-owl:demonym%20?demonym%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28?name%29,%22en%22%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28?demonym%29,%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: This has uncovered a cool new question for me. If I had the string "Norwegian" as Henrik_Ibsen does, how does one identify the country that that nationality value corresponds to? (which would be `http://dbpedia.org/page/Norway`)

Comment: @Kristian I was wondering along the same lines, since there's an obvious difference between "Norway" and "Norwegian".  DBpedia might or might not have this information;  I wonder if WordNet does?

Comment: @Kristian I think when asking for birth place getting country name (Norway) you can then get the dbpedia-owl:demonym property of "Norway" and you would get "Norwegian".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor that's pretty cool. Not to mention, `dbpedia-owl:demonym` sounds pretty metal. \m/

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Found a problem with this. birthPlace is often not just country but city/area. Like him: http://dbpedia.org/page/Sam_Mendes

Not sure how to extract just country out of that...

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong with the query:

1. It's dbpprop:nationality
2. The label doesn't appear to exist, and unless you make that variable optional, it will eliminate the row altogether. **EDIT**: *Joshua Taylor's answer reminded me that the label doesn't exist because the `dbprop:nationality` value is a literal, which cannot be used as a subject resource, therefore, there will never be a label for `dbpprop:nationality`. Instead, where the data exists, you would use `dbpedia-owl:nationality`, which you did originally. it just so happens that Henrik_Ibsen has no `dbpedia-owl:nationality` value associated with him*

Updated query (updated).

```
SELECT
  #### ?label ####    See Edit
  ?nationality

WHERE {
  dbpedia:Henrik_Ibsen dbpprop:nationality ?nationality .
  #### OPTIONAL { ?nationality rdfs:label ?label . } #### See Edit.
}
```